# Understanding the remark about one-dim marginals of isotropic random vectors after lemma 3.2.3 of Roman Vershynin's High-dimensional Probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I quote from Roman Vershynin's High-dimensional Probability page 48

"If x is a unit vector in Lemma 3.2.3, we can view ⟨X, x⟩ as a one-dimensional marginal of the distribution of X, obtained by projecting X onto the direction of x. Then X is isotropic if and only if all one-dimensional marginals of X have unit variance. Informally, this means that an isotropic distribution is extended evenly in all directions."

How does one actually show we only need to consider $<X,e_i$> where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors  as when I try and use the equivalence statement I end up with terms $E[X_iX_j]$ and I dont see how this can be cancelled without the assumptions of independent coordinates (and mean zero vectors)

Link to the textbook: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf